# Why the length of the list does not change?

Tags: python, list

here is my code for an online course, I don't know why the length of the list is still 1

```
tags = soup('a')

for tag in tags: 
    tag = tag.get('href', None)
    tag.strip()
    tag = str(tag)
    tag.split()
    names = []
    names.append(tag)
    print names
    print len(names)
```

it gives back:
    ['http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Conli.html']
    1
    ['http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Cohen.html']
    1

Answer (score 3):

Because this line is inside the for loop:

```
names = []
```

Which means `names` gets reset to `[]` on every iteration of the loop. You should put that line *before* the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
tags = soup('a')
names = []
for tag in tags: 
    tag = tag.get('href', None)
    tag.strip()
    tag = str(tag)
    tag.split()
    names.append(tag)
    print names
    print len(names)
```